# convergence in mean when mean is the constant?

Tags: convergence-divergence

For a random sequenc $X_n$, if its expectation $E|X_n|=0$, does that mean it converges in mean to $0$? 
For convergence in mean to $0$ we need $E|X_n-0|\rightarrow0$

Comment: If $X_n$ converges to $0$ in mean, then $EX_n\to 0$. It is however not sufficient. Convergence in mean means $E|X_n - X| \to 0$, where $X$ is the limit.

Comment: I up-voted this question and its vote total is not zero, so someone down-voted it.  Could that person explain what the objections are?

Answer (score 1):

Convergence in mean to $0$ requires $E |X_n| \to 0$, which is a much stronger condition.  Those absolute values are important!

EDIT:  I see you have now changed the statement to $E|X_n| = 0$.  Then
that does imply convergence in mean to $0$.  But you should be aware
that $E|X_n| = 0$ is equivalent to: $X_n = 0$ with probability $1$.

Comment: what I am confused is not the absolute value part, it is the constant part. In other words, if a sequence is a constant, 0,0,0,0...... does that mean its limit is 0?

Comment: @martingale Yes. Do not confuse limit of a sequence with limit of random variables though

Comment: @Ant  Thanks. so the answer is yes here.

Answer (score 0):

That $X_n$ converges in mean to $X$ as $n\to\infty$ means that
$$
\operatorname{E}|X_n-X|\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$

So convergence in mean to $0$ means that
$$
\operatorname{E}|X_n-0|\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$

The fact that $\operatorname{E}X_n=0$ does not at all imply that $\operatorname{E}|X_n|=0$.

Comment: what if I have the absolute value part? Does $E|X_n|=0$ imply limit is zero?

Comment: If $\operatorname{E}|X_n|=0$ for every $n$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{E} |X_n| = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 0 = 0$. ${}\qquad{}$